Context switching in ChatBot using DialogFlow
I'm trying to create a chat bot for a course website using Dialog Flow. I'm having a few categories let's say they are three subjects (Physics, Chemistry, Maths). I've create CSV files for FAQ's for all the categories. But I am not able to get how to take the context into account when the bot answers a question. For example if the user is currently discussing about Maths then the query should be answered from the FAQ's of Maths because same query can have different answers depending on the subject.
I tried searching on web and the only thing I found was to use webhook to send the query along with the context to backend and then parsing the query using NLP and generating answer from the appropriate FAQ file. But I'm looking for some way to handle it using the Intent feature on DialogFlow.
Can anyone help me figure out if there is any other approach using Intents of Dialog Flow ?
